# python sum of primes

Tags: python, sum, primes

I am tying to make a python program that will generate the sum of primes for a number, but the program is not giving the correct result,please tell me why.

```
b=1
#generates a list of numbers.
while b<100:
    b=b+1
    x = 0.0
    a = 0
    d = 0
    #generates a list of numbers less than b. 
    while x<b:
        x=x+1
        #this will check for divisors. 
        if (b/x)-int(b/x) == 0.0:
            a=a+1
        if a==2:
            #if it finds a prime it will add it.
            d=d+b
print d
```

I made it generate a list of primes successfully, but i could not get the primes to add.

This is the code that i used to generate a list of primes.

```
b=1
while b<1000:
    b=b+1
    n = b
    x = 0.0
    a = 0
    while x<n:
        x=x+1
        if (n/x)-int(n/x) == 0.0:
            a=a+1
    if a==2:
        print b
```

Comment: Do you have the code that you wrote?

Comment: what do you mean? the code is above, or do you mean the code that generated a list of primes.

Comment: @kyle_k I meant do you have the code for summing the list, but I added what to do below.

Comment: Can you be more specific on your goal kyle? Sum of primes for a number = foo(15) = 3+5 = 8?

Comment: Shouldn't the check for `a==2` go outside the inner while?

Comment: Your comments say that you are generating a list, but all of your variables are numbers. Are you sure you know what a [list](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) is?

Comment: I expect that when @kylek says "generate a list of primes" e probably didn't mean 'list' as in Python data type.  As you say, there is no list in the code, so I expect e didn't mean it that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `d` variable is being reset during each iteration of your outer loop. Move the initialization out of that loop.

Additionally, the `a == 2` check should only occur once per iteration of the outer loop. Move it out of the inner loop.

```
b=1
d = 0
#generates a list of numbers.
while b<100:
    b=b+1
    x = 0.0
    a = 0
    #generates a list of numbers less than b. 
    while x<b:
        x=x+1
        #this will check for divisors. 
        if (b/x)-int(b/x) == 0.0:
            a=a+1
    if a==2:
        #if it finds a prime it will add it.
        d=d+b
print d
```

Result:

```
1060
```

While we're at it, let's try cleaning up the code so it's more comprehensible. You can move the inner loop into its own function, so readers can more clearly understand its purpose:

```
def is_prime(b):
    x = 0.0
    a = 0
    while x<b:
        x=x+1
        #this will check for divisors. 
        if (b/x)-int(b/x) == 0.0:
            a=a+1
    if a==2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

b=1
d=0
#generates a list of numbers.
while b<100:
    b=b+1
    if is_prime(b):
        d=d+b
print d
```

It's also useful to use variable names that describe what they represent:

```
def is_prime(number):
    candidate_factor = 0
    amount_of_factors = 0
    while candidate_factor<number:
        #A += B is equivalent to A = A + B
        candidate_factor += 1
        #A little easier way of testing whether one number divides another evenly
        if number % candidate_factor == 0:
            amount_of_factors += 1
    if amount_of_factors == 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

number=1
prime_total=0
#generates a list of numbers.
while number<100:
    number += 1
    if is_prime(number):
        prime_total += number
print prime_total
```

`for` loops are more idomatic than `while` loops that increment a counter:

```
def is_prime(number):
    amount_of_factors = 0
    for candidate_factor in range(1, number+1):
        if number % candidate_factor == 0:
            amount_of_factors += 1
    if amount_of_factors == 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

prime_total=0
#generates a list of numbers.
for number in range(2, 101):
    if is_prime(number):
        prime_total += number
print prime_total
```

If you're feeling bold, you can use list comprehensions to cut down on the number of loops you use:

```
def is_prime(number):
    factors = [candidate_factor for candidate_factor in range(1, number+1) if number % candidate_factor == 0]
    return len(factors) == 2

#generates a list of numbers.
primes = [number for number in range(2, 101) if is_prime(number)]
prime_total = sum(primes)
print prime_total
```

Comment: +1 This is the actual answer to your question. I feel that I should mention if you are going to be using this code for large number `b` you need to 1) only check up to the square root or 2) better yet, *use a sieve*.

Comment: Is really sum of number 1's primes 1060? Also, as I know, sum of 20's primes is 2+2+5=9 not 983. I hoped so I can use this code, but it doesn't work like I excepted!

Comment: @AdriansNetlis, this code finds the sum of all primes that are less than a particular number, and you seem to want to find the sum of all prime factors of a number. Ex. when you replace 101 with 20 in my code, you get 2+3+5+7+11+13+17+19 = 77. Not sure where you're getting 983 from.

Comment: But how to make it get all prime factors from the number and than sum them? But where do you get 101? I just see b = 1 and d = 0. Isn't b the number to replace?

Answer (score 3):

Kevin properly answered the question you asked. Permit me to answer the question you *didn't* ask, but should have: What is the best way to compute the sum of the primes less than *n*. The answer is to use a sieve:

```
def sumPrimes(n):
    sum = 0
    sieve = [True] * (n+1)
    for p in range(2, n):
        if sieve[p]:
            sum += p
            for i in range(p*p, n, p):
                sieve[i] = False
    return sum
```

This code implements the Sieve of Eratosthenes, summing primes as it goes. It works by repeatedly choosing the smallest uncrossed number (*p* in the code above, which is selected when `sieve[p]` is `True`), then crossing out all of its multiples (*i* in the code above, which is incremented by *p* to compute multiples of *p*) starting from its square (since all smaller composites have already been crossed out). A sample use of the function is `print sumPrimes(100)`, which prints 1060, which is the correct answer.

Note that Roland's answer does not implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes, even though he claims that it does; use of the modulo function is the giveaway that Roland's answer uses trial division, *not* the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

If you're interested in programming with prime numbers, I modestly recommend this [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog.

Comment: Thanks, i have been wanting to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes for some time now, but all of the other examples made little sense to me, this one i can understand, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you're doing this for the sake of learning python there are more concise (>> less error-prone) ways of doing this. From your question *I'm assuming you're trying to sum all the prime numbers below and including 100*:

```
sum=0
limit=100
for n in range(2,limit+1):
  if all(n % i for i in range(2, n)):
    sum += n
print sum
```

prints `1060`

Comment: If you're trying to help em learn Python, it would be helpful to explain the more esoteric Python-isms, such as your list comprehension and the functions you use.

Comment: point taken but I'm sure my code is readable enough and gives enough hints to let Google do the rest of the teaching, if learning is indeed the OP's goal.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are a powerful tool in Python. Think of them as a for-loop in steroids. :-) You can use them to implement trial division, which is a simple way of finding primes.

It works like this:

```
In [4]: sum(prime_list(100))
Out[4]: 1061
```

The `prime_list` function:

```
def prime_list(num):
    """Returns a list of all prime numbers up to and including num.
    Based on trial division.

    :num: highest number to test
    :returns: a list of primes up to num

    """
    if num < 3:
        raise ValueError('this function only accepts arguments > 2')
    candidates = range(3, num+1, 2) # (a)
    L = [c for c in candidates if all(c % p != 0 for p in range(3, c, 2))] #(b)
    return [1, 2] + L
```

Now for the explanation. With the exception of 2, all prime numbers are odd. So all the odd numbers from 3 to `num` (100 in this case) are candidates for prime numbers. Let's generate a list of those as done at (a):

```
In [5]: num = 100

In [6]: range(3, num+1, 2)
Out[6]: [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99]
```

For an odd number `c` to be prime, one must ensure that `c` modulo all previous odd numbers `p` must be non-zero. Let's say `c` is 25.

```
In [7]: c = 25
```

Then `p` is in:

```
In [8]: range(3, c, 2)
Out[8]: [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23]
```

Now check `c` modulo `p`:

```
In [9]: [c % p != 0 for p in range(3, c, 2)]
Out[9]: [True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

As we know 25 % 5 == 0, so the second item in the list is `False`. However, for a number to be prime, all items in the list must be true:

```
In [10]: all(c % p != 0 for p in range(3, c, 2))
Out[10]: False
```

So 25 is not a prime.

Let's try again for `c` is 41:

```
In [11]: c = 41

In [12]: range(3, c, 2)
Out[12]: [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39]

In [13]: [c % p != 0 for p in range(3, c, 2)]
Out[13]: [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]

In [14]: all(c % p != 0 for p in range(3, c, 2))
Out[14]: True
```

And indeed 41 is a prime.

So prime_list returns a list of primes:

```
In [15]: prime_list(100)
Out[15]: [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

To sum that up we simply use the `sum()` function:

```
In [16]: sum(prime_list(100))
Out[16]: 1061
```

**Edit:** Based on the comments, I tried the improvement that WillNess suggested and a real sieve using sets:

```
def prime_list(num):
    if num < 3:
        raise ValueError('this function only accepts arguments > 2')
    candidates = range(3, num+1, 2)
    L = [c for c in candidates if all(c % p != 0 for p in range(3, c, 2))]
    return [1, 2] + L

def prime_list2(num):
    if num < 3:
        raise ValueError('this function only accepts arguments > 2')
    candidates = range(3, num+1, 2)
    L = [c for c in candidates if all(c % p != 0 for p in
         range(3, int(math.sqrt(c))+1, 2))]
    return [1, 2] + L

def prime_list3(num):
    candidates = set(range(3, num+1, 2))
    results = [1, 2]
    while candidates:
        t = list(candidates)[0]
        results.append(t)
        candidates -= set(range(t, num+1, t))
    return results
```

Some timings for `num=100`:

```
In [8]: %timeit prime_list(100)
1000 loops, best of 3: 180 us per loop

In [9]: %timeit prime_list2(100)
1000 loops, best of 3: 192 us per loop

In [10]: %timeit prime_list3(100)
10000 loops, best of 3: 83.9 us per loop
```

And `num=1000`:

```
In [11]: %timeit prime_list(1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.05 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit prime_list2(1000)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.43 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit prime_list3(1000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 ms per loop
```

`num = 5000`:

```
In [14]: %timeit prime_list(5000)
1 loops, best of 3: 166 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit prime_list2(5000)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit prime_list3(5000)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.3 ms per loop
```

And finally `num=50000`:

```
In [18]: %timeit prime_list3(50000)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.49 s per loop

In [19]: %timeit prime_list2(50000)
1 loops, best of 3: 170 ms per loop
```

Comment: make that `if all(c % p != 0 for p in range(3, sqrt(c)+1, 2))` for *big* gains in speed. :) If `sqrt` computation takes up too much time, re-write this as a simple loop, with the check `p*p <= c` (might be faster).

Comment: @WillNess: Interesting. It works fine (at least up to 10000 :-) ), but what I don't see yet is why?

Comment: but how much is the speed gain? Now about "why": if `a*b == n` and `a >= sqrt(n)` then surely `b =< sqrt(n)`, so you would have encountered *it* before the `a`. One of them is `<= sqrt(n)` for sure, if there are any `a,b` such that `n == a*b`. So if we got to the `sqrt` and still didn't found such a number, - *it's a prime*.

Comment: @WillNess: I added some timings

Comment: what about my explanation? :) -- your new code: if prime_list3(n) were optimal impl'n of sieve of Erat's, it would be faster than prime_list2(n) which is only a suboptimal trial division. you can stop subtracting sets when `t` is above `sqrt(num)`. At this point all the numbers left in candidates are prime numbers. **But** this won't help it: turning a set into list on each iteration (to find its minimal elemt, right?) spoils the overall complexity hopelessly. You need to generate primes below sqrt(num) separately, for set subtractions. Can you use the sieve method for that??

Answer (score 0):

Just sum the list using the code you used to generate the list:

```
d = sum(d)
print d
```

Comment: What list are you referring to? There aren't any lists in the OP's code. `d` is an integer.

Comment: "I made it generate a list of primes successfully." The code he didn't post, but said he achieved.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_of_prime(num):
        if num < 2:
            return 'Please enter values greater than 2'
        if num == 2:
                return 2
        sum = 0
        for j in range(2,num):
                for i in range(2,j):
                        if (j % i) == 0:
                                break
                else:
                        print j
                        sum = sum + j
        return sum
num = int(raw_input())
result = sum_of_prime(num)
print result
```

Comment: wouldn't your call `sum_of_prime(3)` return 2 also? that's not consistent with returning 2 for `num=2` then. and what about the efficiency? how do your [empirical orders of growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) compare with the other answers?